# TCP transport long bytes with Aleph

Tags: tcp, clojure, aleph

I am trying to build RCP server based on `aleph`. It passed on all the test, but when the byte array for send or receive become large, the bytes seems been corrupted.

For example. I tried to send a byte array which length is 2936, but I only got 1024 bytes at server

I followed the example and did my own modifications for `nippy`. The encoding and decoding will be done by handlers themselves.

```
(defn wrap-duplex-stream
  [s]
  (let [out (s/stream)]
    (s/connect out s)
    (s/splice out s)))

(defn client
  [host port]
  (d/chain (tcp/client {:host host, :port port})
           #(wrap-duplex-stream %)))

(defn start-server
  [handler port]
  (tcp/start-server
    (fn [s info]
      (handler (wrap-duplex-stream s) info))
    {:port port}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made my own codec for byte array.
It is simple, but to figure how to make use it with gloss and aleph is time consuming

```
(defn buffer->byte-array [buf-seq]
  (byte-streams/to-byte-array buf-seq))

(defn bytes-codec []
  (reify
    Reader
    (read-bytes [this buf-seq]
      (let [buf-seq (dup-bytes buf-seq)
            byte-arr (buffer->byte-array buf-seq)]
        [true byte-arr nil]))
    Writer
    (sizeof [x]
      nil)
    (write-bytes [x y byte-arr]
      [(ByteBuffer/wrap byte-arr)])))

(def protocol
  (gloss/compile-frame
    (gloss/finite-frame
      :uint32
      (bytes-codec))
    #(nippy/freeze %)
    #(nippy/thaw %)))


(defn wrap-duplex-stream
  [s]
  (let [out (s/stream)]
    (s/connect
      (s/map #(io/encode protocol %) out)
      s)
    (s/splice
      out
      (io/decode-stream s protocol))))

(defn client
  [host port]
  (d/chain (tcp/client {:host host, :port port})
           #(wrap-duplex-stream %)))

(defn start-server
  [handler port]
  (tcp/start-server
    (fn [s info]
      (handler (wrap-duplex-stream s) info))
    {:port port}))
```